# Question on singularities of a complex analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Let $D^*=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0< |z| < 1\}$ and $f: D^* \to \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function such that $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{|z|}$ on $D^*$ then such a $f$,

(a) necessarily extends to an analytic function on the unit disc

(b) necessarily has an essential singularity at $z=0$

(c) has at most a simple pole at $z=0$

(d) can have a pole of order $2$ at $z=0.$

I know basic definitions and concepts of analytic function and singularities but don't know how to approach such a problem, any hint is much appreciable

Thank you.

Comment: what can you say about $zf$? given that $|zf| \le 1$ from the hypothesis?

Comment: @Conrad I think it should be analytic.

Comment: yes, so then what can you deduce about $f$? eg if $zf=1$ or if $zf=z^2$ which both satisfy the required inequality

Comment: then $f$ can have at the most simple poles. But can we construct some counter-examples that satisfy the hypothesis and eliminate the options?

Comment: $1/z$ works and eliminates $a$ while $b,d$ are excluded by the above reasoning